# Invoking webservice "Unable to connect to the remote server" in webapplication but ok in console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-applications, console-application

I have a very strange behavior. I have a ASP.NET 3.0 console application which invokes a webservice to send sms.

I'm trying to replicate the same thing in a ASP.NET 4.0 web application but when I invoke the webservice it turns me a error when I invoke the method to send sms:

*There was no endpoint listening at webservice.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.*

**InnerException** *Unable to connect to the remote server*

**InnerException.Message** *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond webserviceIP:80*

I use the exact same code and the exact same configuration in booth web and console applications:

```
var soap = new Service.WebServicesSoapClient();
soap.SendSMS(smsUser, smsPassword, number, message, originator);
```

--

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServicesSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="webservice.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebServicesSoap" contract="Service.WebServicesSoap" name="WebServicesSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any idea on what is blocking my web application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: must have different configurations, or the requests are different in some relevant way. Compare both and analyse the differences.

Comment: I already do this in, all I can imagine, different ways

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler http://fiddler2.com/, to capture the requests.

Comment: You will not believe but when I run my application with fiddler2 running I can send sms but when I turn it off, I can't send again. When fiddler is running I can't access my TFS to...